# Hibernate ManyToMany and Restrictions.in

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, criteria, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have `Article` and `Tag` entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article implements Serializable{
   //other things

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
   private List<Tag> tags;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag implements Serializable{
    //other things

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags" ,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Article> articles;
}
```

And the idea is: I have 3 `Article`s when **First** has `first` and `second` tags. **Second** has `second` and `third` tags. **Second** has `first` and `third` tags. When I filter `Article`s by `first` tag, I get two `Article`s - because first and third `Article`s was tagged with `first` tag. When I filter `Article`s by `second` tag and `third`, I got all 3 `Article`s - because every `Article` was tagged with one of them. Generally, the goal is to filter `Article`s by one of specified `Tag`s. I wrote a Unit test which shows what I want to achieve:

```
@Test
public void test_WhenTagIdsAreSpecified_ArticlesShouldBeFilteredByOneOfTags() throws Exception {
    AuthorDTO author = getExpectedAuthor();
    List<TagDTO> tags = saveThreeTags();
    TagDTO firstTag = tags.get(0);
    TagDTO secondTag = tags.get(1);
    TagDTO thirdTag = tags.get(2);
    service.save(new ArticleDTO(null, author,
            Arrays.asList(firstTag, secondTag), articleContent + "_firstAndSecondTag"));
    service.save(new ArticleDTO(null, author,
            Arrays.asList(secondTag, thirdTag), articleContent + "_secondAndThirdTag"));
    service.save(new ArticleDTO(null, author,
            Arrays.asList(firstTag, thirdTag), articleContent + "_firstAndThirdTag"));

    assertEquals(3, tagService.getAll().size());
    Collection<Long> tagIdsContainingFirst = Collections.singletonList(firstTag.getId());
    List<ArticleDTO> articlesByFirstTag = service.getByTags(tagIdsContainingFirst);
    Collection<Long> tagIdsContainingSecondOrThirdTag = 
        Arrays.asList(secondTag.getId(), thirdTag.getId());
    List<ArticleDTO> articlesBySecondOrThirdTag =
        service.getByTags(tagIdsContainingSecondOrThirdTag);

    assertEquals(2, articlesByFirstTag.size());
    assertEquals(articleContent + "_firstAndSecondTag", articlesByFirstTag.get(0).getContent());
    assertEquals(articleContent + "_firstAndThirdTag", articlesByFirstTag.get(1).getContent());
    assertEquals(3, articlesBySecondOrThirdTag.size()); //it fails
}
```

But instead of 3, I got 4 `Article`s which is pretty weird cause I have only 3 in database. That is how I try to filter `Article`s:

```
@Override
public List<Article> getByTags(Collection<Long> tagIds) {
    return (List<Article>)createCriteria()
            .createAlias("tags", "t")
            .add(Restrictions.in("t.id", tagIds))
            .list();
}
```

Second tag is counted twice (I think because it has `second` **and** `third` tags). It seems like it *"loops"* in every `Tag`, then check if it is in (`second`, `third`) and then if it's true add `Article` related with `Tag`. I also tried to add `Restrinction.in` for every tag ID separately:

```
criteria.createAlias("tags", "t");
for (Long tagId: tagIds) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("t.id", Collections.singleton(tagIds)));
}
```

But then result was 0, no expected 3 - IMO also because it doesn't look on all `Tag`s, bot on every `Tag` separately. Is there any idea how to *"look on all tags at once"* (if you know what I mean)? When I want to achieve something like that in normal language it would be a little bit like (Java-like pseudocode):

```
for (Article article: articles){
    List<Tag> tags = article.getTags();
    // As many conditions as tags to filter specified
    if ( tags.contains(second) || tags.contains(third) ... ) {
        filteredArticles.add(article);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with this problem? Thank you in advance for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on my own:

```
@Override
public List<Article> getByTags(Collection<Long> tagIds) {
    return (List<Article>)createCriteria()
            .createAlias("tags", "t")
            .add(Restrictions.in("t.id", tagIds))
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .list();
}
```

`.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)` was missing.